# If $\Bbb E[Z_n]\xrightarrow[n\rightarrow\infty]{} 0$ then can we say $Z_n=0$ with high probability?

Tags: probability, graph-theory, random-graphs

This is in the context of subgraph containment problem. Say I managed to prove that a certain subgraph $H$ (like a triangle or a small cycle) of an Erdos-Renyi graph $G$ on $n$ verticies with edge probability $p$ ($G\sim\text{ER}(n,p)$) satisfies $$\Bbb E[\text{# times }H\text{ appears in }G ]=1/n$$ which goes to zero ($p$ being specified in the question as some function of $n$).

Is this enough to say that "$G$ does not contain $H$ with high probability"?

Comment: In that case, since this random variable has a non negative integer range, then $P(Z_n\geq1)\leq 1-1/n$. So the answer is yes.

Comment: you should specify what you mean by $Z_n=0$ with high probability

Comment: @NL1992 I think you meant $P(Z_n\ge 1)\le 1/n$

Comment: For some reason I can’t seem to edit my last post, but of course I meant $P(Z_n<1)\geq1-1/n$. Second, this is because Markov inequality gives $P(Z_n\geq1)\leq E(Z_n)/1$.

Comment: @Monty I think he means $P(Z_n=0)\rightarrow1$

Comment: @NL1992 You should post an actual answer as opposed to writing answers in the comments. (Then you'll be able to do convenient things like edit after five minutes have passed.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, almost. I have seen it written that way. The best way to put it is that the probability that $H$ appears goes to 0 as $n$ increases. Or the $Z_n$s go to 0 with high probability, with $Z_n$ as you defined. Note the following claim:

> Claim 1: Let $Y$ be a random variable that takes on nonegative integral values. Then
> $\Bbb{E}[Y] \ge \Bbb{P}[Y > 0]$.

This claim is easy to show. So if you are given a series $\{Y_n\}$ of rvs where $Y_n$s are a sequence of r.v.s as in the hypothesis of Claim 1 where $\Bbb{E}[Y_n] \le n^{-1}$ it follows that
the $Y_n$s go to 0 with high probability as well.

As $\#\{$times $H$ appears in $G\}$ is a random variable that takes nonegative integers, it follows from Claim 1 that

$$\frac{1}{n} \ge \Bbb E[\text{# times }H\text{ appears in }G ] \ge \Bbb P[\text{# times }H\text{ appears in }G ]$$

Comment: What does "go to $0$ with high probability" mean, when the definition of "with high probability" already incorporates a limit?